# Gremlin GraphTraversalSource spawn a random GraphTraversal

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to use one GraphTraversal only to add all vertices to remote graph db.
However, I
can't make the add query to be together like:

```
GraphTraversalSource source = ...;
source.addV().addV().....next();
```

Because I need to do processing to get each vertex,
I am thinking structure to be like:

```
GraphTraversalSource source = ...;
GraphTraversal g = source.??; <create a graph traversal>

while (condition)
{
    ...
    g.addV();
}
...

g.next();
```

Idea is GraphTraversalSource spawns a graphTraversal and it can be passed along,
finally I use terminate step to send command to remote graph db.

However, I am not sure how to make GraphTraversalSource to create a proper GraphTraversal in this case, is source.V() a good fit? I think this may create unnecessary step to find all vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `inject()` a throwaway object to start the stream:

```
GraphTraversalSource g = ...;
GraphTraversal t = g.inject(0);

while (condition)
{
    ...
    t.addV();
}
...

t.iterate();
```

Some folks don't like that I suppose in which case I guess you'd have to do a `null` check of some sort:

```
GraphTraversalSource g = ...;
GraphTraversal t = null;

while (condition)
{
    ...
    if (null == t)
    {
        t = g.addV();
    } 
    else 
    {
         t.addV();
    }

    ...
}
...

t.iterate();
```

Personally, I think `g.inject(0)` makes a lot of sense if you think in Gremlin terms, but I can see where others might prefer a more explicit creation of `t`.